# What are these strange seeds that looks like a mini porcupine which you can find all over Germany?

Tags: plants, germany, plant-identification

These were in abundance throughout Germany and looks kinda strange.

[image: Image of a strange seed/fruit in Germany]

Comment: These are not specific to Germany, you will find them in abundance in the United Kingdom, for example.

Comment: How did you never see a common chesnut before?

Comment: I grew up in the U.K. And hadn't seen a Conner until I was an adult. Even then I hadn't seen this spiky bit until relatively recently. They are not ubiquitous.

Comment: Indeed I was also surprised to learn that someone could have not seen one.

Comment: I should have stated that i noticed this in my second week of being in Germany. I live in India and never seen anything like this here :)

Comment: It's a sea urchin fossil.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These are not exactly the seeds, but the hull of the seeds of [the horse chestnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus_hippocastanum).

[image: Chestnuts.]

Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aesculus_hippocastanum_fruit.jpg

Comment: Horse chestnuts are sometimes colloquially known as conkers.

Comment: And, by the way, the German name is basically the literal translation "Rosskastanie". Where a "Ross" is another name for "Pferd" (horse), and "Kastanie" means chestnut.

Comment: More by the way: you can see the nuts themselves (which are sometimes also called buckeyes in American English) on the ground in your photo. They are poisonous. However, you can also find real/sweet chestnut trees in Germany (Esskastanien/Edelkastanien/Kastanien/Maronen) which have similar looking nuts and also spiky hulls (but those spikes are made of very many needle-like spines which will make your hands itch).

Comment: @Max - we have sweet chestnuts in the UK too, and if those spikes only make your hands itch then you must have very, very tough hands indeed! Those spikes go straight through gardening gloves and skin if I'm not careful :-)

Comment: You don't often find round sweet chestnuts (though they do exist). Most commonly two or three grow in a single (very prickly) hull, and so the nuts have one or two flat sides. In contrast conkers / horse chestnuts are most often round.

Comment: In the UK at least, they're mostly known by children for a particular game played with the seeds inside: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conkers

Comment: As the German word suggests, they are sold as a snack especially during winter time. It is very high in fat and warms you very gently, also your hands while carrying in your pockets. Here an example picture: http://www.br.de/themen/ratgeber/inhalt/gesundheit/esskastanien-dpa100~_v-img__16__9__xl_-d31c35f8186ebeb80b0cd843a7c267a0e0c81647.jpg?version=d9f9a

Comment: @Spratty: Agreed on the chestnut spikes. They also go through mountain bike tires like butter - biking in such areas during autumn can be really frustrating... :P

Comment: @Aravona I've been conked, and have conked a few with chestnuts back in the day here in Canada. A green chestnut on the end of a twig is the closest I've ever come to charging into battle with a mace.